# php - trying to echo a returned join My_SQL query with a foreach loop

Tags: php

The following code prints the words every line and then breaks, which is what I coded it to do.

However, I want it to be more clever and try printing `*$single*` on the same line three times, so it will say the users first name, last name, and their order description all on the **same line**.

How can I go about doing this?

```
<?php 
//turn off error reporting for security
//connecting to database as mysqli class
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "banana2", "cool");  
if($db->connect_errno){
     echo $db->connect_errno;
}
$query1 = $db->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, orders.order_description FROM 
users JOIN orders on users.id=orders.employee_id");
$sharp = $query1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

function doAgain($sharp){
 foreach($sharp as $single){
    if(is_array($single)){
        doAgain($single);
    }
    else{
        echo $single."<br>";  
    }
 }    
}

doAgain($sharp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single `foreach` loop that prints each row on a single line:

```
foreach ($sharp as $row) {
    echo "$row[first_name] $row[last_name] $row[order_description]<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the function doAgain?

```
$rows = $query1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value) {
        echo $value . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: i like your logic a lot, but dont understand how $fieldname=>value comes into play, does it have to do with the fetch_all function?

Comment: oh you can just use ($row as $value) - value will be the value of each column so you don't have to name them

Answer (score 0):

mySQL columns are indices of the array. For example, you could echo

```
echo $single['first_name'].$single['last_name'];
```